# Random occurrence of "Cannot redefine..." error

Tags: php, windows, iis

PHP 5.6, Windows Server 2016, IIS 10

The error is familiar to anyone in PHP:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare mainContent() (previously declared in [the controller file]:12) in [some included file] on line 29
```

Here's the thing: *this error just appears*. A program that has been working for days and hasn't been touched just starts throwing the error. When I restart IIS the error goes away and everything goes back to working normally.

This is similar to this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30075

So here's what it's not:

- The function isn't declared twice, anywhere in the program. The function name in question "mainContent" is reserved and used once and only once in any program.
- Every include/require is *include_once* or *require_once*, no exceptions, so it's not a double-include.

I am sure of these two facts because I'm the only developer, so there's no one else to make changes, let alone break the code without me knowing.

When I search for a solution, all I find whether I'm on Google / Bing / Yahoo / stackoverflow / reddit is the usual explanations of *double-include* or *declared the function twice*. The error just shows up on an untouched program that's been working for days without this error, then goes away with an IIS restart. It's not in the code!

I can't be the only person who's ever encountered this problem, but I can't find a solution.

(I intend to upgrade the site to PHP7, but it's not a 1 <=> 1 transition and the client's daily business tolerates no down-time so I'm stuck here for a while longer.)

Comment: It may be easier to think about your issue and offer some help if you are able to share some relevant code.

Comment: Thank you, but the code is not relevant. It's all in the explanation: one moment there is no error, the next moment there is. No code has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example to reproduce the problem you have reported:

```
<?php
function foo(int $a) {
    echo $a;
    echo "\n";
}

function bar(int $b) {
    echo $b;
    echo "\n";
}

echo "I'm running. gonna redeclare\n";

function foo(int $x) {
    print "i'm the redeclared foo\n";
}

foo(23);

echo "finito\n";
```

You can save it to a file named "test.php" and execute it with 
php "c:\path\to\test.php"

The error message is telling you that you a function with the same name has been declared twice.

Mind you, if this is a web app, then the concept of "running for days" is not exactly correct because each request to a specific PHP script in a web application is a new execution of the script in a sort of clean-slate environment. Some state may be shared such as the Session, and out of band data like files and database objects, but that's about it.

Unless it's some kind of long-running script, then the number of days is not relevant.

It's entirely possible that this code-path simply only gets traversed in some specific conditions.

Without any additional context, this is the best I can offer.

Comment: I'm sorry if my description is unclear, and I thank you for taking the time reiterate what a dozen google searches have already said, but, forgive me, it appears that you haven't read what I wrote. A little clarification: once it occurs the error is persistent and restarting IIS fixes the issue. Am I incorrect in believing that restarting IIS doesn't make changes to code that would fix a function re-declaration if it existed?